# Find child xpath count in appium with parent xpath

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, appium

I need to get the child xpath for the given parent xpath. Using the below code but it returns 0.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(parentXpath));
System.out.println("list "+list.size());
```

```
parentXpath - xpath /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View


childsXpaths - xpaths

0 - 
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]

1- 
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]

2- 
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]
```